# Append a digit to all the values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I append all the values of a column with a fixed digit at the end? Specifically I have a column (of datatype number(6,0) ) with 5 digits. I need to put a "0" at the end of each value in the column. So for say "12345", I need to change this to "123450" for the whole column.

Does anyone know how to do this? Perhaps some variant of a string concat (except with the number datatype).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order to add a `0` to a number column I would just multiply by `10` this way:

```
update table set num = num * 10
```

If you need to add a different number rather than `0` you just add the number too:

```
update table set num = num * 10 + 7
```

That would add a `7` at the end to all num values.

Comment: No need to say thank. That's what accepting answers is there for :)